# How do I retrieve a list of the pages visited on a particular day using the Google Analytics API?

Tags: php, api, python-2.7, google-analytics, pageviews

We use Google Analytics on our site to track page views, and I am interested in getting a list of which pages were viewed on a given day.  I'm not looking for the number of times a page was viewed primarily, as I know that this information is available if we need it.  Rather I want a list of all of the unique URLs visited on the site for a given day.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

You can query the landing page dimension and visitor metric to get that data. For more info here is Google Analtyics [query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) and [dimensions/metrics reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Slightly longer answer:

Here is the dimension you would want to use.

```
ga:landingPagePath
```

Here is the metric you would want to use.

```
ga:visitors
```

This will give a report of the urls for the date range you want and the amount of traffic it got. If you don't care about the actual traffic you can just remove that once the data is pulled.

Here is more info/examples about [google's data api's](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/) for python

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with using the API, selecting these two dimenions:

- Page
- Date

and any of the relevant **page-level** metrics (pageviews, unique pageviews, etc.) will product the desired report.

Try using this [link to shared-report from GA Query Explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/?dimensions=ga%253Adate%252Cga%253ApagePath&metrics=ga%253Apageviews%252Cga%253AuniquePageviews&sort=ga%253Adate%252C-ga%253AuniquePageviews&start-date=2014-01-21&end-date=2014-02-04&max-results=50), I believe those are the numbers you want.